# How use CGContextDrawImage in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cgcontextdrawimage

I have an `UIImage` extension that uses `CGContextDrawImage`.
It simply rotate a `UIImage`.
I updated to Xcode8 and Swift3 and cant figure out how to use `CGContextDrawImage`.

I got error on CGContextDrawImage.

> "Cannot convert value of type "CGImage.Type to expected argument type 'CGImage?'"

My code is :

```
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)
```

And whole extension :

```
extension UIImage {
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
    let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rectZero = CGPoint(dictionaryRepresentation: CGRect.zero as! CFDictionary)
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: rectZero!, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap!.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    bitmap!.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }

    bitmap!.scaleBy(x: yFlip, y: -1.0)

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately searching with "cgcontextdrawimage swift3" does not lead me to the thread... Thanks for finding it!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 3, many functions for `CGContext` are imported as an instance method of `CGContext`, the property name `CGImage` has renamed to `cgImage`. And `CGRectMake` is removed.

Try this:

```
    bitmap!.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height))
```

(Hope `!` would be safe for your usage.)

[func draw(CGImage, in: CGRect, byTiling: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/2427134-draw)